# How to call particular CSS file only for desktop not for mobile

Tags: css, menu, hide

Can any one tell me how to call particular CSS file when site opens in Desktop versions hided in mobile versions

Comment: Such questions are [not appropriate for this site](http://bit.ly/dcqznq) and will be [closed](http://bit.ly/18T95z1) or [deleted](http://bit.ly/10c3VuR). Be sure to familiarize yourself with [what type of questions you can or should ask](http://bit.ly/r0ZSEc). If you have any question about this, feel free to ask on [Meta](http://bit.ly/SgO5J) or check the [FAQ] and see the [About] page for general information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 768px)" href="style.css" />
```

More documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Note that all browsers will download that file, even if the media query doesn't apply to them.